# Problem starting with Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mvvm, caliburn

i am starting to learn MVVM, and i decided to choose [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com) to try it out. i am just at the [building part](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Obtain%20and%20Build%20the%20Code&referringTitle=Documentation) (or before that even). i am opening the project. 1st i got an error saying i need to install some silverlight stuff. installed them. now i just get

```
One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly.

// output window
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Caliburn.Micro\src\Caliburn.Micro.WP7\Caliburn.Micro.WP7.csproj : error  : The project file 'D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Caliburn.Micro\src\Caliburn.Micro.WP7\Caliburn.Micro.WP7.csproj' cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation.
```

i guess i didnt install any windows phone 7 stuff? i am not really needing that, just want to work with WPF part of the framework. so how can i continue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply remove the Caliburn.Micro.WP7 project from the solution and you should be able to build the Caliburn.Micro assembly.  You can then reference that assembly and System.Windows.Interactivity.dll to get up and running.